Why must useSearchParams() cause components to be client-side rendered in Next.js App Router?
According to https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/missing-suspense-with-csr-bailout using useSearchParams() in a component will cause at least the component's subtree to not be rendered on the server at all.

Why is this the case with useSearchParams() but not usePathname()?
Why is this the case at all? Can't Next.js just look at the search params in the request the same why it would look at the path and render an initial screen?


Ah I think I might be getting it... https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params says that if it's statically rendered, which my app (for now) is, then it this happens, but if it's dynamically rendered then it should be rendered normally during SSR.
